# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. Nested function

Tags: python, closures

I am trying to run this small python script, but I get an error when I try to print.

Why does this happen?
How can I solve it?
The code is:

```
   # Define echo
   def echo(n):
       """Return the inner_echo function."""

       # Define inner_echo
       def inner_echo(word1):
           """Concatenate n copies of word1."""
          echo_word = word1 * n
          return echo_word

       # Return inner_echo
       return inner_echo

# Call echo: twice
twice = echo(2)

# Call echo: thrice
thrice = echo(3)

# Call twice() and thrice() then print
print(twice('hello '), thrice('hello '))
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 22, in <module>
  print(twice('hello '), thrice('hello '))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

However if I do:

```
copy2=twice('Haha ')
```

And I call

```
copy2
```

I get:

```
In [106]: copy2
Out[106]: 'Haha Haha '
```

But if I try to print it I get error again:

```
In [107]: print(copy2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    print(copy2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I do not understand what it is going on, and how to solve it.

Comment: No repro. The code you posted has a syntax error, and upon fixing that syntax error, the code works.

Comment: This code has incorrect indentation, which suggests that this is not the actual code you are using.  Please post your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the indentation of the function made the code work in my IDE. The function in your code is one tab too far to the right. The code below works as intended

```
# Define echo
def echo(n):
    """Return the inner_echo function."""

    # Define inner_echo
    def inner_echo(word1):
        """Concatenate n copies of word1."""
        echo_word = word1 * n
        return echo_word

    # Return inner_echo
    return inner_echo


# Call echo: twice
twice = echo(2)

# Call echo: thrice
thrice = echo(3)

# Call twice() and thrice() then print
print(twice('hello '), thrice('hello '))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think the intendention was wrong when writting the code here.
But!
I have just pasted the code, and same problem.

I'm running in DataCamp. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Sometimes your code re-formats when you paste it into stack overflow, but you can and you should correct manually after pasting it . Never the less, I don't have experience using Data Camp but I see no reason that what i have posted is should not work

Comment: Thank you. 
I think the problem is in the IDE of dataCamp.